# Add Graph API via az ad app permission fails

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I'm attempting to add the Graph API via CLI 2.x. Here is the PowerShell script I'm running:

```bsh
    #
    # (1) Register the app, replyUrl, enable implicitflow
    #
    Write-Host " -  Create Application " + $appName
    az ad app create --display-name "$appName" --reply-urls "$replyUrl" --oauth2-allow-implicit-flow true

    #
    # (2) get the app id into a variable
    #
    $appId=$(az ad app list --display-name $appName --query [].appId -o tsv)

    #
    # (3) API Permissions, add Graph API/Permission (delegated)     
    #
    Write-Host " -  Add Graph API/Permission (delegated)"
    az ad app permission add --id $appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --api-permissions 311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6=Scope
    
    #
    # (4) Grant permissions based on the error/warning from the previous step     
    #
    Write-Host " -  Grant permissions"
    az ad app permission grant --id $appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
```

I pulled the `--api-permissions id` from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaddevsup/guid-table-for-windows-azure-active-directory-permissions).
The script line `az ad app permission add` throws this error (or warning):

> az : Invoking `az ad app permission grant --id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is needed to make the change effective
> At C:\temp\CP\CreateAppRegistration.ps1:42 char:5
> az ad app permission add --id $appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c00 ...
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invoking "az ad...hange effective:String) [], RemoteException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I then attempt to call the script in the error `az ad app permission grant` and get the following error:

> az : Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url:
> https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2PermissionGrants?$filter=clientId%20eq%20%27e62c4745-cccc-cccc-cccc-71e5599261fc%27&api-version=1.6
> At C:\temp\CP\CreateAppRegistration.ps1:45 char:5
> az ad app permission grant --id $appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c ...
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Operation faile...api-version=1.6:String) [], RemoteException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Can someone help me understand if I need to execute the script (#4 above) per the error generated from #3 above??
Or why is #3 above returning an error/warning?

I say warning because the Graph API does seem to get added but I'm not sure it's in the proper state per the error message.

> `az ad app permission grant --id xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is needed to make the change effective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you **need** to execute the script (#4 above) per the warning generated from #3 above.

You get "404 Client Error: Not Found for url" means the endpont `https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2PermissionGrants?$filter=clientId%20eq%20%27e62c4745-cccc-cccc-cccc-71e5599261fc%27&api-version=1.6` returns null result.

The cmd `az ad app permission grant` will query it first and then insert the new permission. The error occurs in the querying step. I don't think this is reasonable. Your requirement is to add a permission grant, but this cmd needs to query the existing permission grant first. If the result is empty, it prevents you from adding it.

So the logic for this cmd `az ad app permission grant` is not perfect currently. It may work better for an existing Azure AD app (which has a service principal), but not for a new created Azure AD app (which has no service principal).

A workaround is to use `az ad app permission admin-consent --id $appid` instead of `az ad app permission grant`. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-admin-consent). It covers what `az ad app permission grant` can do.

After you execute `az ad app permission admin-consent` for once, it will generate a service principal for the Azure AD app and then you can use `az ad app permission grant` later.

Comment: Is there a way to catch, or suppress, the output from the command "az ad app permission add..."? It shows like an error but reads like a warning.  I'm working in powershell

Comment: @user2503078 Yes. You need to update the Azure CLI to the latest version and use `--only-show-errors` global parameters. For example `az ad app permission add --id $appid --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --api-permissions 311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6=Scope --only-show-errors`. It only shows errors, suppressing warnings. If my answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.